# How to write to /var/log/system.log on a Mac

Tags: osx, logs

I am tailing the system.log on a mac:

```
tail -f -n 0 /var/log/system.log
```

but I can't figure out how to write to this log. It does seem to be the main log on the machine. I tried:

```
logger foobar  # didn't work
syslog -s -l error "message to send"  # didn't work
```

anyone know how to write to the system.log on a Mac?

**update**:

if I run: `log stream`

and then use:

```
logger -is -t krypted "Hello L"
```

it will show up in the stream, but not in `/var/log/system.log`. weird.

Comment: note that on ubuntu for example, `logger xyz` will log to /var/log/syslog, but on macos, this file appears to be /var/log/system.log, but using logger doesn't seem to write to it by default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The streaming messages are part of a binary log file. Apple are moving to a unified logging system, so the logs do not work the same way anymore, at least by default. One might try to configure `syslogd` and/or ASL (Apple System Logger) via one or both of the configuration files, `/etc/syslog.conf` and `/etc/asl.conf`. (There are many more configuration files for ASL stored in `/etc/asl`.) This might involve grokking manual pages to learn how to produce plain text log files for certain messages. Some of these manuals might be `man 1 log`, `man 1 syslog`, `man 5 syslog.conf`, and `man 8 syslog`. I have not yet determined exactly how to do this, but I wanted to give you some sort of method to produce, view, and "tail" custom messages. (I'll come back and update this answer if I ever do learn how to send certain messages to a plain text file by configuring their new logging system. It seems that it, at least, *can* be done, because there do exist plain text files in `/var/log`.)

---

One can send messages with `syslog -s` and `logger`. (The `-s` option sends log messages to `syslogd`, and `syslog` can do more than `logger`.) An easy way to follow the logs in a similar way to `tail` is to utilize `Console.app`. Open the program and place the cursor on the local machine listed under *Devices*. In the search field, provide the name of the program that was used to send the message: one of `syslog` or `logger`. Next, open a terminal and send a message.

```
syslog -s "test message"
```

The message can then be seen in the Console as illustrated below.

[image: Snippet of Apple Console]

Messages can be acquired from the logs. Use the `--info` and/or `--debug` options to specify lines that `log` would ignore by default. Specify which process sent the syslog message within the `--predicate` option.

```
log show --info --debug --predicate "process == 'logger'"
```

or

```
log show --info --debug --predicate "process == 'syslog'"
```

---

To get an effect similar to `tail`, use the `stream` command.

```
log stream --info --debug --predicate "process == 'logger'"
```

or

```
log stream --info --debug --predicate "process == 'syslog'"
```

After starting the stream, send a message to witness that it does behave in a similar way to `tail`, as illustrated.

[image: Apple log command streaming]

The command, `syslog -s "test message"` was used to send the messages.

Comment: More log-released resources: https://eclecticlight.co/consolation-t2m2-and-log-utilities/

Comment: I tried (in Mojave) to open Console and search for ANY:syslog and entered the `syslog -s "test message"` but nothing shows up.

Comment: @gctwnl Since I wrote the answer Console has gotten weird. Try the command line. Still works great for me on Big Sur and Mojave.